# Main.storyboard not found

Tags: ios, storyboard, simulator

I have been trying  to figure out solution to the following error:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could       not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle 
    <../Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/FA7AFF8D-48A6-4C4D-    AE92-B15CF6641C4B/myApp.app> (loaded)'
    *** First throw call stack:
```

Tried all possible solutions given in stack overflow. Nothing worked!!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please explain your already tried solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Build Phases** -> **project target** -> **Copy Bundle Resources** -> + -> Add storyboard here.If it is there than delete and add.

Clean project and Build and run

Answer (score 2):

in your `Info.plist` file find "Main storyboard file base name" and change value for your storyboard's name example "MainStoryboard"